# Confusion with repeated exponents

Tags: exponentiation

When someone writes:

$3^{3^3}$

> Do they mean $3^{(3^{3})}=3^{27}$ OR ${{(3^3)}^3} = 27^3$ ?

*There are no brackets*

Please reply ... this may be a silly question ... Thanks!

Comment: I once read that most people, regarding exponentiation, and when ambiguity is present, consider the order to be from right to left. This would mean that it is $3^{27}$.

Comment: Generally, the exponent is carried only by the single closest factor, and grouping symbols must be used to extend the scope of the exponent. So you likewise have that $ab^c$ means $a (b^c)$ and not $(ab)^c$, and that $a+b^c$ means $a+(b^c)$ rather than $(a+b)^c$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation $a^{b^c}$ with no brackets would conventionally be $a^{(b^c)}$, as opposed to $(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$.  Thus, in this case $3^{27}$ is probably indicated.